# What is the correct way to create an index for LIKE query - Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have created an index for an Item table that needs frequent searching by category id and item name like below.

```
- Table -
    "id"                 bigserial    NOT NULL,
    "category_id"        integer      NOT NULL,
    "item_name"          varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    "description"        varchar(500)
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    CONSTRAINT "FK_item.category_id" FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "category" ("id")
```

`create index item_cat_and_name_like on item (category_id, UPPER(item_name) text_pattern_ops);`

the search query I use is like below (findAllByCategoryIdAndItemNameStartingWithIgnoreCase()).

`select * from item where category_id = 1 and UPPER(item_name) LIKE UPPER('item%');`

but the created index is not working for it. I tried `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in psql shell. but for the query below it is working.

`select * from item where category_id =1 and UPPER(item_name) = UPPER('item001');`

What am I doing wrong? What is the proper way to create an index for a LIKE query?

- EDIT-

```
explain analyze select * from item where category_id = 1 and UPPER(item_name) LIKE UPPER('item%');
                                             QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on item  (cost=0.00..31.50 rows=511 width=582) (actual time=0.021..0.561 rows=511 loops=1)
   Filter: ((category_id = 1) AND (upper((item_name)::text) ~~ 'ITEM%'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 489
 Planning Time: 0.229 ms
 Execution Time: 0.585 ms
```

```
explain analyze select * from item where category_id = 1 and UPPER(item_name) = UPPER('item%');
                                                          QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using item_cat_and_name_like on item  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=582) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=0 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((category_id = 1) AND (upper((item_name)::text) = 'ITEM%'::text))
 Planning Time: 0.224 ms
 Execution Time: 0.045 ms
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) for the query not using the index generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added what you requested (I think)

Comment: The LIKE condition returns more than 50% of the rows of the table. In that case The Seq Scan is more efficient.

Comment: Just check with query that returns lower number of rows. You are correct, now it's using the index. Thanks for the help!